# Basic Lisp function - sum of even minus sum of odd

Tags: sum, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a function which takes as parameter a `List` and calculates the `sum of even numbers` minus the `sum of odd numbers`.
Here is my implementation but I have no clue why it is not working as expected, could you give me any hints about whats wrong?

```
(defun sumEvenOdd (R)
  (cond
    ((NULL R) 0)
    ((and (ATOM (CAR R)) (= (mod (CAR R) 2) 0))
              (+ (CAR R) (sumEvenOdd (CDR R))))
    ((and (ATOM (CAR R)) (not (= (mod (CAR R) 2) 0)))
              (- (CAR R) (sumEvenOdd (CDR R)) ))
    ((LISTP (CAR R)) (sum (sumEvenOdd  (CAR R)) (sumEvenOdd  (CDR R))))
    (T  (sumEvenOdd  (CDR R)))
  )
)
```

Comment: It seems you are subtracting the sum from the even number.  Also you use + one place and sum another place. Perhaps a better approach would be to flatten, negate evens, then add them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the code algorithm, it fails because how the math is being done.
How the code is now, this the evaluation being done with the list (list 1 2 3 4 5) is (- 1 (+ 2 (- 3 (+ 4 (- 5 0))))) that equals 5.
What we were expecting was (2+4)-(1+3+5) that equals -3. What's wrong?
Basically the sum operation in math is commutative, while the subtraction operation is not. 1+5 and 5+1 is the same. 1-5 and 5-1 is not.
This reflects on the code on the last operation where 5 is being subtracted 0.

The simplest solution is to adjust the operation order, switching the arguments.

```
(defun sumEvenOdd (R)
  (cond
    ((NULL R) 0)
    ((and (ATOM (CAR R)) (= (mod (CAR R) 2) 0))
              (+ (sumEvenOdd (CDR R)) (CAR R)))
    ((and (ATOM (CAR R)) (not (= (mod (CAR R) 2) 0)))
              (- (sumEvenOdd (CDR R)) (CAR R)))
  )
)
```

That way the evaluation will be: (- (+ (- (+ (- 0 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) that equals -3.

PS: You can check and test the code here: http://goo.gl/1cEA5i

Comment: Well your math observation is correct, so i will  accept your answere as soon as you fix the idea regarding  car, car can be a list, this  operation is supposed to work on every level of a binary tree. edit and i will accept and upvote

Comment: Regarding the CAR, I was on the premise that it would be a list containing only numbers. Since it's a binary tree constructed with lists, of course CAR can be a list.

That being said, don't forget that the solution code given above assumes the list being given contains only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Here is an edited version of your code:

```
(defun sumEvenOdd (R)
  (cond
    ((NULL R) 0)
    ((and (ATOM (CAR R)) 
          (= (mod (CAR R) 2) 0))
     (+ (sumEvenOdd (CDR R)) (CAR R))) ; switched places for consistency
    ((and (ATOM (CAR R)) (not (= (mod (CAR R) 2) 0)))
     (- (sumEvenOdd (CDR R)) (CAR R))) ; operands needed to be switched
    ((LISTP (CAR R)) (+ (sumEvenOdd  (CAR R)) ; what is sum? replaced with +
                        (sumEvenOdd  (CDR R))))
    (T  (sumEvenOdd  (CDR R)))))
```

Here is a solution using reduce:

```
(defun sum-even-odd (list)
  (reduce (lambda (acc e)
            (cond ((consp e) (+ acc (sum-even-odd e)))
                  ((not (numberp e)) acc) ; perhaps not needed
                  ((oddp e) (- acc e))
                  (t (+ acc e))))
          list
          :initial-value 0))

 (sum-even-odd '(1 2 (3 4 (5 6) 7) 8 9 10)) ; ==> 5
```

If you are certain the list only has numbers or other lists with numbers the check for something that is not `consp` nor `numberp` would be redundant. This does not work for dotted lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are answers with how to fix your code, but let's look at a different implementation.
You don't specify that your function needs to work on a tree so this is for a flat list of numbers.

```
(defun sum-even-odd (r)
  (- (apply #'+ (remove-if-not #'evenp r))
     (apply #'+ (remove-if-not #'oddp r))))
```

`remove-if-not` takes a list and a predicate function. It run the predicate on each element of the list and create a new list only containing the elements where the predicate didn't return nil.

`apply` takes a function and a list and calls the function with the arguments being the elements of the list. so `(apply #'+ '(1 2 3 4))` is equivalent to `(+ 1 2 3 4)`

Common lisp has good functions for workings with lists (and many other data types) check em out and your code can end up much cleaner.

Also never use camel-case (or any case based naming) in common lisp and symbols are case insensitive. The symbols `HeLloThErE` and `hellothere` and `helloThere` are **the same symbol**. This is why you will see hyphens used in names.